# SSRS 2012 Document Types not showing up in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

I've tried:
1. Installing it from the original SQL Server 2012
2. Installing it from the SQL Server 2012 SP1 iso
3. Downloading the add-in from Microsoft and running it
4. I followed these steps http://chrishattonnzlsp.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/missing-report-server-content-types-rssharepoint-add-in-sharepoint-2013/

I was eventually able to at least get the add-in install to work (or at least not fail). But now the Reporting Services Document Types (datasets, datasources, reports, etc.) aren't available as a content type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the ssrs add-in to install properly was a complete pain. I think it had to do with the fact that we did development on the server prior to installing the ssrs add-in. I ended up un-joining the farm, re-joining it, then installing the component. That got it to work. Then I just had to re-deploy solutions, re-activate features and re-configure my web.config.